# How to simple make string uppercase in F#?

Tags: string, f#, formatting

Try to make as described:

> To convert a string to lowercase, you can call the String.ToLower()
> method

```
let makeUpperCase s = 
  s.ToUpper()
```

Get as result

> error FS0072: Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on
> information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be
> needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the
> object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved.

Comment: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/troubleshooting-fsharp/#FS0072

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to invoke members of a value that is passed as an argument to a function, you have to give F# some hint about what the type of the value is. The best way to do this is using a type annotation:

```
let makeUpperCase (s:string) = 
  s.ToUpper()
```

F# compiler needs this, because it cannot figure out what `ToUpper` method are you trying to invoke as there may be many .NET objects that have a method of this name.